# How to use 'cut' command for finding temperature using tlp?

Tags: command-line, cut-command

I have installed [tlp](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html) in my system to prevent laptop over heating and i used this code to retrieve currtent cpu temperature.

```
tlp-stat -t
```

the output for above command is something like this:

```
--- TLP 0.7 --------------------------------------------

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    47 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)
```

can you tell me how i can retrieve only the integer part of that output (ie 47). I tried using cut command but i am unable to find an optimum result.

this is the cut command i used

```
tlp-stat -t | cut -d= -f2
```

and the output is

```
--- TLP 0.7 --------------------------------------------

+++ Temperatures
    49 [°C]
 (not available)
```

How to refine my `cut` command to get only the integer two digit value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about: `tlp-stat -t | head -4 | tail -1 |cut -c29-30`

Answer (score 6):

With awk:

```
... | awk '/CPU temp/ {print $4}'
```

with grep:

```
... | grep -oP '^CPU temp.*=.* \K[0-9]+'
```

with sed:

```
... | sed -nE 's/^CPU temp.*=.* ([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Nice answers, but the question asked how to do it with the cut command.

Comment: @MikeScott [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: cut is unfortunately unsuitable.